# Ошибка, связанная с str_ends_with

Tags: php, строки, substring

Есть оператор

```
while ($example=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $sizememorydatasql='SELECT name as name FROM goods WHERE id='.$example['goods_id'];
                $sizememorydataquery=$pdo->prepare($sizememorydatasql);
                $sizememorydataquery->execute();
                $sizememorydataitem=$sizememorydataquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['name'];
                $sizememorydata = explode(',',$sizememorydataitem)[4];
                
                if (str_ends_with($sizememorydata, 'SSD')) {
                    $sqloutput[$i]['sizememorydata']=trim(substr($sizememorydata,0,strlen($sizememorydata)-strlen('SSD')),' ');
                    $sqloutput[$i]['memorytype']='SSD';
                }
                else {
                    $sqloutput[$i]['sizememorydata']=trim($sizememorydata,' ');
                    $sqloutput[$i]['memorytype']='HDD';                     
                };

                
                // $sqloutput[$i]['screendiagonal']=$example['screendiagonal_id'];
                
                $i+=1;
                
                // $return['outputtext'].='</div>';
            };
            
            $return['outputtext'].='</div>';
            $sqlcountrecords = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM monoblocks';
            $querycountrecords=$pdo->prepare($sqlcountrecords);
            $querycountrecords->execute();
            $return['countrecords']=$querycountrecords->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['count'];
                    

        //Return json encoded results
        return json_encode([
                            'result' => $return,
                            'output' => $sqloutput
                           ]
        );
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_ends_with() in C:\OSPanel\domains\testsite.ru\stackoverflowsite\php\ajaxsubcategory1.php:127 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\testsite.ru\stackoverflowsite\php\ajaxsubcategory1.php(162): ajaxValidate->formValidate() #1 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\testsite.ru\stackoverflowsite\php\ajaxsubcategory1.php on line 127
```

Подскажите как устранить ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте Вашу версию PHP, эта функция доступна для PHP 8 и выше.

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-ends-with.php

Для PHP 7.4 можно использовать такую функцию:

```php
/**
 * @param string $haystack
 * @param string $needle
 * 
 * @return bool
 */
function endsWith(string $haystack, string $needle): bool
{
    $count = strlen($needle);
    
    if ($len === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return (substr($haystack, -$count) === $needle);
}
```

Для Вашей версии PHP 7.0 функция должна выглядеть так:

```php
/**
 * @param string $haystack
 * @param string $needle
 * 
 * @return bool
 */
function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    $count = strlen($needle);
    
    if ($len === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return (substr($haystack, -$count) === $needle);
}
```

Использование:

```php
$string = 'Hello World';

print_r(endsWith($string, 'World')); // true
```

Comment: а какие есть версии команд в рhp 7.0?

Comment: @devsitesite substr()

Comment: Обновил ответ :)